# How to use $geoNear with embedded GeoJsonPoint field?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, geospatial

I have a collection for places with the following fields:

```
{
"name":"AAAAA",
.
.
"location" : {
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            25.381911,
            37.109551
        ]
    }
    .
    .
 }
 }
```

I want to use aggregation with geoNear and I cannot find a way to set the field for the location. With a query like this:

```
db.places.aggregate([
{
 $geoNear: {
    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
    distanceField: "dist",
    maxDistance: 2,
    query: {  
            "categories.categoryList":"Cocktail Bar"
        },
    includeLocs: "location.loc",
    num: 5,
    spherical: true
 }
```

}]);

I get this error:

```
"errmsg" : "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }"
```

I think the problem is that the "loc" field is embedded in the location document and I cannot "tell" mongo to search near "location.loc".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution finally was to not include the GeoJsonPoint in the embedded location document. I just used "loc" in the same way as name and MongoDB "understood" that there were coordinates in the document.